# Is there an easy way to put time ticks on a parametric plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a parametric plot showing a path of an object in x and y (position), where each is a function of t (time), on which I would like to put a time tick, every second let's say.  This would be to indicate where the object is moving fast (widely spaced ticks) or slow (closely spaced ticks).  Each tick would just be short line that crosses the plot at that point in time, where that short line is normal to the plotted curve at that location.

I'm sure I can figure out a way to do it using lots of calculations and graphics primitives, but I'm wondering if there is something built-in that I have missed in the documentation that would make this easier.

(Note: this is about ticks on the plotted curve itself -- this doesn't have anything to do with the ticks on the axes or frame.)

Comment: As an option to your plot, try `Mesh -> 50`

Comment: Thanks.  `Mesh` gets close to what I want.  If the parametric plot range is `{t,a,b}`, then it appears I can use `Mesh->Round[(b-a)/10]` to get dots every 10 seconds.  (Obviously it works best if `b-a` is a multiple of 10.)  Now I need to figure out how to turn those into perpendicular line segments.  I see that I can set Mesh to a list of tick locations each with a graphics directive ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create the ticks perpendicular to the curve, I calculate the direction of the normal to the curve where the ticks are to be placed and then orient a line segment along that direction. The following code does that.

```
ClearAll[ParametricTimePlot]
SetAttributes[ParametricTimePlot, HoldAll]
ParametricTimePlot[fun_, {var_, min_, max_, steps_}, len_, 
    opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Show[
        ParametricPlot[fun, {var, min, max}, opts],
        Graphics[
            Rotate[Translate[Line[{{-len/2, 0}, {len/2, 0}}], #1], ArcTan @@ #2]
        ] & @@@ (N@Table[{fun, RotationMatrix[π/2].D[fun, var]} /. var -> i, 
            {i, min + steps, max, steps}])
    ]
```

Use the above function as:

```
ParametricTimePlot[{ Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sqrt[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, 
    π/10}, 0.1, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

---

If you want to keep it simple and just show the dots, then this is very straightforward:

```
ClearAll[ParametricTimePlot]
SetAttributes[ParametricTimePlot, HoldAll]
ParametricTimePlot[fun_, {var_, min_, max_, steps_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=     
    ParametricPlot[fun, {var, min, max}, opts] 
    ~Show~
    ListPlot[Table[fun /. var -> i, {i, min, max, steps}], 
        PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]

ParametricTimePlot[{ Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sqrt[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Comment: There's a more compact way to do your second routine. Witness `ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sqrt[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/10]}, MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], PlotStyle -> Blue]`.

Comment: @MarkAdler Could you add an example of the functions you're plotting?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I noticed wxffles' comment after I'd written it. Will fix in the next edit

Comment: @MarkAdler Are your functions smooth or at least, differentiable once?

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Your `ParametricTimePlot` with line segment ticks is working perfectly with my interpolating functions.  Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to get the ticks to use PlotStyle.  To do that, I changed Line[...] to {OptionValue[PlotStyle],Line[...]}.  That actually worked, but now I get a bunch of nastygrams about unknown options for ParametricTimePlot for the other options that I'm passing to ParametricPlot (Frame, FrameLabel, etc.).

Comment: @MarkAdler That's because I had intended to only supply the options to `ParametricPlot`, not use them in any other way, so didn't define any defaults. To do what you want, replace the `opts` in the definition with `opts : OptionsPattern[Options[ParametricPlot]]`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkAdler Even simpler would be just using `OptionValue[opts, PlotStyle]` (no need to change `opts`)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to find analytically the parallel line yourself, and then creating a `Graphics[]` with all the lines. Here is a rough working example that's specific to this one expression and scales the lines according to the differential of the function, but it outlines the gist of the idea.

```
Show[
Line /@ Table[
Evaluate[
     {Cos[t^2], Sin[t^2]} + 
        (0.1/2 tickpoint D[{Cos[t^2], Sin[t^2]}, t] // {#[[2]], -#[[1]]} &)
]
, {t, 0, 2.5, 0.05}, {tickpoint, {-1, 1}}] // Graphics,
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t^2], Sin[t^2]}, {t, 0, 2.5}]
]
```

[image: ParametricPlot combined with ticks showing regular intervals of the parameter]

Answer (score 2):

I couln't get nice little lines so I've used filled circles instead. I hope this works.

I've spaced the points out but Pi/4 on the curve in this example.

```
f = {Sin[#], Sin[2 #]} &
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[u], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}],
 ListPlot[f /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Black]]
 ]
```

"[image: Mathematica graphic]"