# How to change the number of markers in Plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Two questions, but I am not sure whether they are already answered or not.

- How can I create `PlotMarkers` (in `ListLinePlot`) with less points (less markers)? Or markers with some intervals. I have tried the Mesh option, but it does not work; it messes up all the plots.
- Is it possible to create `PlotMarkers` for normal `Plot`, not `ListPlot`? One way is to export the data to the list, but I would like to do it directly.

More information:
Suppose `ListLinePlot` of a number of data lists with legends.
based on the suggestions, I have changed my plots into this, but honestly I cannot understand how it works!

```
style = Sequence @@ {Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.5}, None, None}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, FontSlant -> Plain], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSlant -> Plain], 
   AxesStyle -> Lighter@Gray, TicksStyle -> Black, 
   LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], 14, FontSlant -> Plain, 
     FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio}

  ListLinePlot[{c1, c2, c3, c4}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  Evaluate@style, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Long, S_Short, Short, Flexible}, Below], 
  PlotStyle -> (Directive[
       AbsoluteThickness[2], #] & /@ (ColorData[81] /@ Range[6])), 
  MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#1] &, Abs[#1] &, Abs[#1] &, Abs[#1] &}, 
  Mesh -> 6, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}, 
  MeshStyle -> {ColorData[81] /@ Range[6], ColorData[81] /@ Range[7], 
    ColorData[81] /@ Range[8], ColorData[81] /@ Range[9]}]
```

The output is something like this, where as you can see each Markers has all the colours together. 
How can I solve this problem and improve it? 
Another problem is the distribution of the Markers which is not good.

[image: the output!]

Comment: Regarding the first question you could create two plots, one with the `ListLinePlot` with all the data, the second would be a `ListPlot` with the desired number of data (e.g. each 2) with `PlotMarkers`. Then `Show` would make it fit :)

Comment: Regarding the second question, I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50587/1356) should help.

Comment: @Öskå Thanks for your replies. Let me try!

Comment: @Öskå, your first answer works, but how can I handle the PlotLegends in this case?

Comment: I don't have _v9_ so I don't know much about `PlotLegends`. Does `Show` remove it?

Comment: @Öskå, it duplicates the legends, I should find a way to mixed the lines and markers together; unite them.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't tell you much about `PlotLegends` :)

Comment: @Öskå, eldo, If it is OK, I keep the question open until tomorrow.

Comment: You better do that indeed :)

Comment: I like the question because, IMO,  it is a semantic mistake of _Mathematica_ to misuse `Mesh` as a vehicle to change marker numbers.

Comment: @eldo, exactly, in all the available software, Mesh has clear meaning and application!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First question if you don't want to play with `Mesh` you could do:

```
data = Thread@{Range@10, Range[1, 100, 10]}
llp = ListLinePlot[data];
lp[n_] := ListPlot[data[[1 ;; Length@data ;; n]], PlotMarkers -> Automatic];
Table[Show[llp, lp@i], {i, 1, 10, 2}]
```

[image]

Second question:

[Eldo's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50615/1356) or [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50587/1356):

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Mesh -> 5] /. 
 Point[x : {__Integer}] :> Map[Inset["■", #] &, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can do both at once with something like `Point[x:{__Integer}]:> Map[Inset["■", #] &, x[[;;;;5]]]`  (+1)

Comment: @Öskå, I could not solve the problem so I used your idea of combining two plots together. Thank you and the other for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`MeshStyle` option setting can be a function, so you can use that function to reduce the number of mesh points and to specify the markers:

```
Row[{Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Mesh -> 20, ImageSize -> 400, MeshStyle -> Red],
     Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Mesh -> 20, ImageSize -> 400, 
       MeshStyle -> 
        (Map[Inset[Style["\[FilledSquare]", Red, 36], #] &, #[[;; ;; 4]]] & @@ ## &)]},
 Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

One can use the same trick with `ListLinePlot`:

```
data = Thread@{Range@10, Range[1, 100, 10]};
Row[{ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 400, MeshStyle -> Red],
   ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 400, 
    MeshStyle -> 
      (Map[Inset[Style["\[FilledSquare]", Blue, 16], #] &, #[[;; ;;3]]] & @@ ## &)]}, 
 Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's much better indeed :)

Comment: @kguler, Thank you. I am trying to do it for multiple data lists and include legends as well. I will comment if I fail.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second part of your question:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/4]}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8]}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

As to the first part of your question: Follow the link provided by Öska.

Comment: @Öska - please change `ListPlott` (I tried to edit, but you have to change more than just one character).

Comment: I did sorry :) I just noticed.. :)

Comment: @eldo Thank you. I should change it a little for multiple plots with legends.