# Marking specific points on a 3D curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

Here is the curve below. (written as a position vector)

```
r = {Cos[7 Pi*t], Cos[6.2*Pi*t], 2.5*t}
ParametricPlot3D[r, {t, 0, 2}]
```

I want to know how I can mark specific points on this curve, for example when `t = 0` and `t=1`.

I would also like to label those points.

Comment: You should start with checking related posts, see e.g. [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952) Three dimensional problem is not especially more difficult, nevertheless it depends on what kind of visualization you expect, see e.g. [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612) for vectors instead of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `MeshFunctions` but you need to "cheat" to include the t=0 point, e.g.

This is an edited post based on the correct comments by Oska and gpap. In my original answer I used the equivalent of Function[{x,y,z,t},z] though my intention was Function[{x,y,z,t},t]. I have corrected and now labelled the points.

```
r[t_] := {Cos[7 Pi*t], Cos[6.2*Pi*t], 2.5*t};
Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, -0.01, 2}, MeshFunctions -> (#4 &), 
  Mesh -> {{0., 1}}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03], Red}], 
 Graphics3D[
  MapThread[
   Text[Framed[#1], r[#2], {1, -1}] &, {{"Position 1", 
     "Position 2"}, {0, 1}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way i can label those points?

Comment: Shouldn't be the end point (`t = 2`) placed at the end of the curve? The `t=1` point is wrong as well I'm afraid.

Comment: @Oska the OP specifically mentions t=0 and t=1 hence my mesh points...I have only displayed and not labeled so will revise when I get chance

Comment: What I meant is that.., since the function is plotted from 0 to 2, for `t=2` the point should be in the end right? (at the top in that case)

Comment: @Öskå is right. Your mesh function is now labelling the curve at the point where its `z` value is 1 and not at the point where the parameter `t` is 1. In `ParametricPlot3D` the option `MeshFunctions` takes four arguments, the x, y, z coordinates and the parameter along the curve. You can either replace `MeshFunctions -> (#3/2.5 &)` or `MeshFunctions -> (#4 &)` to get the right result. Then you'll have (at least) an upvote :)

Comment: @gpap thank you (and Oska) for pointing out my mistake...you are both absolutely correct that I am  merely showing the z values and not the parameter...will correct...

Comment: No problem - this would be my preferred method too (hence the upvote)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Graphics3D` and `Show`:

```
r[t_] := {Cos[7 Pi*t], Cos[6.2*Pi*t], 2.5*t} ;
Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2}],
 Graphics3D[{
   PointSize@0.05, Point[r[#] & /@ {0, 1}],
   Text[#, #2] & @@@ 
    Thread[{{"Start", "Middle"}, {0, 0, .2} + # & /@ (r@# & /@ {0, 1})}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `Mesh` (credit: [this answer by @BobHanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50633/125) )

```
r = {Cos[7 Pi*t], Cos[6.2*Pi*t], 2.5*t};

ParametricPlot3D[r, {t, 0, 2},  Mesh -> {{#, {PointSize[0], 
  Text[Framed@Style[Round@#, Red, Bold, 16], r /. t -> #]}} & /@ {0.00001, 1, 1.99999}}]
```

[image]