# How can I display a plot as points instead of a connected line?

Tags: plotting

I have a parametric plot that, when put into Wolfram|Alpha, makes a graph. The function is as follows:

`parametric plot ( 1*sqrt((2*1.5*1*n)/1)*cos(sqrt((2*1.5*1*n)/1)),  1*sqrt((2*1.5*1*n)/1)*sin(sqrt((2*1.5*1*n)/1)) ), n = 0..40`

The final part, `n = 0..40`, is an arithmetic sequence that describes the range of the plot (which is a spiral).

How can I make W|A display, instead of a smooth line, 40 unconnected points?

Thank you very much!

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50581/2079  (Simply add `PlotStyle->None` to get rid of the line )

Comment: Note that questions like "How can I make W|A display" are off-topic: ["Some kinds of questions are considered **off-topic**: Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay)..."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing:

```
ParametricPlot[Sqrt[3 n] {Cos[Sqrt[3 n]], Sin[Sqrt[3 n]]}, {n, 0, 40}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
ListPlot[Table[Sqrt[3 n] {Cos[Sqrt[3 n]], Sin[Sqrt[3 n]]}, {n, 0, 40}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I get:

[image]

which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give Mathematica a shot. Do you know if it's possible in Wolfram|Alpha itself?

Answer (score 0):

@TeM_I count 41 points in your ListPlot:

ListPlot[Table[Sqrt[3 n] {Cos[Sqrt[3 n]],Sin[Sqrt[3 n]]},{n,0,40}],Axes->None,AspectRatio->1]

I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have 50 points.

@snazzybouche : I understood you asked to display 40 points, not 41 points.

My statement was correct. Why the down vote?

Comment: 41 would be correct as the array of points starts at 0

Comment: this seems to be exactly the same as TeM's answer. I didn't vote but that might be why.

Answer (score 0):

@george2079_I basically used TeM's code to show that there were indeed, 41 points plotted. The OP asked for 40 points, not 41. This will plot 40 points:

ListPlot[Table[Sqrt[3 n] {Cos[Sqrt[3 n]],Sin[Sqrt[3 n]]},{n,0,39}],Axes->None,AspectRatio->1]

If the OP is satisified with the answer previously given, that's fine. I have no problem with that. I was just asking why I was down voted when my answer was true. If we're drilling holes in a part, 41 holes would ruin the piece, and be cause for rejection.